# Jebrains Webstorm 6.0.2 Live Edit Showing " Jetbrains IDE Support is Debugging this Tab " in chrome 29 but changes are not reflected

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webstorm, liveedit

**Jetbrains Webstorm 6.0.2**
**Google Chrome 29**

Please Help my Google Chrome shows "Jetbrains IDE Support is Debugging this Tab"..
But I cant see any change reflected on the Page.
Please Help me by providing a fix for my problem. 
Thanks for answering.

Comment: Can you better explain what you are trying to do?  I can't tell if this message is expected and you are purposely trying to do some debugging, or if the message is unexpected and you are trying to get it to go away.  A better description of what you are doing before and after this message appears will help others give you a potential answer to your problem.

Comment: @Derek : AFAIK this message is expected in chrome. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCVwdvufTds for more demo on live edit please watch this YT video. The only Diffrence between video demo and me is that the changes does'nt appear for me as i write the code. Hope I was able to Convey my problem

Comment: what file are you trying to edit - html, css, or? Does the problem occur for all files/changes? Please can you attach the contents of Chrome extension console (see http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/LiveEdit, How do I know what's wrong?)

Comment: @lena : I am trying to edit Html Page. http://pastebin.com/CCwFmYMM . Hope this Helps ..

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this problem. It was fixed with the new LiveEdit update for webstorm 7. You can download [it from here](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/).

I'm afraid I can't offer anything more than that. This has been a known issue.

Comment: Installed Webstorm 7 with latest chrome plugin.. Still no changes are reflected on browser as i write the code. Can I make this work by using older version of chrome or webstorm?

Comment: @user93830 Not all changes will be visible instantly. Try changing the Css, and see what happens.

Comment: @ Games Brainiac : Even the normal text in <body> tag is not visible instantly. I dont think css will change anything for me.please help me with another solution.Thanks for giving time.